# Web browsers(3) aren't loading page completely, in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer

I have a 'new' (had it for 4 months now) Windows 8 machine (Samsung Series 7 Gamer). I've installed 3 browsers in it, for which I use for different purposes.  Chrome for personal stuff, Firefox for impersonal stuff, and IE for work related stuff.

They all share an ailment which is that at times web pages don't load completely. It's easiest to notice when loading Gmail or Google Docs because there seems to be more to load and it will render a partial web page, but any other website is just as susceptible.

I had thought it was only Chrome until I realized it was occurring in Firefox also. I use IE the least but it has happened in IE as well.  There seems to be little rhyme or reason to when this occurs, other than the longer its been since I've rebooted (left to sleep overnight) the likelier this will occur.  And secondly, if I've come to a website for the first time, it's less likely to occur.

Sometimes, clearing the browser cache (for all time) seems to work for a while, but I can't even determine how strongly that's correlated since sometimes right after clearing the cache I still immediately get problems.

This post seems relevant: [Google Chrome not loading web pages correctly unless multiple refreshes](https://superuser.com/questions/517137/google-chrome-not-loading-web-pages-correctly-unless-multiple-refreshes) but this doesn't seem to say anything with regards to Firefox or IE.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a different DNS server, like Google's (8.8.8.8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm answering my own question here in hopes that others find this as a useful solution.  The fix required two parts, one obvious and one not so obvious.

Chrome was the browser that seemed the most sensitive.  It seemed that something may have become corrupt in the Chrome user profile. Deleting the Chrome user profile helped.

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120714152207AAsFJ82

For me, it seemed that this accounted for a majority of the problems.  However, 5% of the time I still had problems loading web pages.  For this I feel silly, as it turned out both my wireless and wired interfaces were turned on, and thus the solution was simple, turn off wireless.  On many other computers I've never had this issue, but it seems on this laptop I did.